# bookmarklet to trigger javascript code buried in iframe and framesets

Tags: javascript, iframe, bookmarklet

I'm faced with having to go through a few hundred iterations of selecting "All" checkboxes, selecting the next page (1-10 in a drop down) then selecting "All" again.

The page selection drop down and the "All" link are buried in an iframe.

I was hoping to write a bookmarklet that would at help speed up the process. Two bookmarklets to go back and forth between them would be better than nothing.

path to the dropdown
html/body (AppFrameBody)/table (_AppFrameBaseTable)/iframe (AppBody)/frameset (outerFS)/frameset (widgets)/frameset (innerFS)/frame (Detail)/form (form1)/select (nSetNumber, onchange="doSubmitPageChange(false)")

path to the "All" link
html/body (AppFrameBody)/table (_AppFrameBaseTable)/iframe (AppBody)/frameset (outerFS)/frameset (widgets)/frameset (innerFS)/frame (Detail)/form (updateForm)/
All

I've tried using getElementById to dig all the way down but haven't had any success.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkfox/

Comment: Thanks. may not have been clear... there is an All link that selects all the check boxes.  more looking for 1) click "all" link 2) select the next page 3) click "all" link and repeat for 10 pages.

Comment: That is only 20 clicks... Not worth a bookmarklet in my opinion

Comment: thanks for the input.  I actually had to repeat that process 450 times.  there will be times in the future that I have to go through this so I would like to get something put together.

Comment: Can you load the page out of the frame? Does it have some kind of number in the url, can you generate the form it is in ? It all sounds like a better idea than a bookmarklet. I would hack the form in an editor and submit each set or one big set with one script

Comment: nope.  I've tried pulling the iframe source out and dropping it but the list doesn't populate.  they have it referring to the parent somewhere...